# Neural Network with tanh wrong saturation with normalized data

Tags: neural-network

I'm using a neural network made of 4 input neurons, 1 hidden layer made of 20 neurons and a 7 neuron output layer.

I'm trying to train it for a bcd to 7 segment algorithm.  My data is normalized 0 is -1 and 1 is 1.

When the output error evaluation happens, the neuron saturates wrong.  If the desired output is `1` and the real output is `-1`, the error is `1-(-1)= 2`.

When I multiply it by the derivative of the activation function `error*(1-output)*(1+output)`, the error becomes almost `0` Because of `2*(1-(-1)*(1-1)`.

How can I avoid this saturation error?

Comment: So this may just be not my domain but I have absolutely no idea how it is possible to troubleshoot this from the information given.  I also don't know if "tanh" is a typo or a hyperbolic tangent.

Comment: tanh is hperbolic tangent :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Saturation at the asymptotes of of the activation function is a common problem with neural networks. If you look at a graph of the function, it doesn't surprise: They are almost flat, meaning that the first derivative is (almost) 0. The network cannot learn any more.

A simple solution is to scale the activation function to avoid this problem. For example, with tanh() activation function (my favorite), it is recommended to use the following activation function when the desired output is in {-1, 1}:

```
f(x) = 1.7159 * tanh( 2/3 * x)
```

Consequently, the derivative is

```
f'(x) = 1.14393 * (1- tanh( 2/3 * x))
```

This will force the gradients into the most non-linear value range and speed up the learning. For all the details I recommend reading Yann LeCun's great paper [Efficient Back-Prop](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/index.html#lecun-98b).
In the case of tanh() activation function, the error would be calculated as

```
error = 2/3 * (1.7159 - output^2) * (teacher - output)
```

Comment: The derivative is wrong, should be:
`f'(x) = 1.14393 * (1- tanh^2 ( 2/3 * x))`

=> `f'(x) = 0.6667 * 1.7159 * (1 - tanh(2/3 *x)) * (1 + tanh(2/3 * x)))`

=> f'(x) = 0.6667 / 1.7159 * (1.7159 - 1.7159*tanh(2/3 * x)) * (1.7159 + 1.7159*tanh(2/3 * x))'

=> `f'(x) = 0.6667/1.7159 * (1.7159 - f(x))*(1.7159 + f(x))`

Comment: I checked the derivative numerically https://github.com/hughperkins/ClConvolve/blob/master/notes/numericbackprop.gnumeric , and your formulae is correct Fukuzawa.

Answer (score 1):

This is bound to happen no matter what function you use. The derivative, by definition, will be zero when the output reaches one of two extremes. It's been a while since I have worked with Artificial Neural Networks but if I remember correctly, this (among many other things) is one of the limitations of using the simple back-propagation algorithm.

You could add a [Momentum factor](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Learning_and_neural_networks#Momentum_learning) to make sure there is some correction based off previous experience, even when the derivative is zero.

You could also train it by epoch, where you accumulate the delta values for the weights before doing the actual update (compared to updating it every iteration). This also mitigates conditions where the delta values are oscillating between two values.

There may be more advanced methods, like second order methods for back propagation, that will mitigate this particular problem.

However, keep in mind that tanh reaches -1 or +1 at the infinities and the problem is purely theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure if I am reading the question correctly, but if so, you should scale your inputs and targets between 0.9 and -0.9 which would help your derivatives be more sane.

Comment: @danelliotster Can you edit your answer to show how the derivative will be saner. I downvoted in a moment of haste. I can't undo it now unless there is an edit.