# changing activation function from Sigmoid to Tanh?

Tags: c#, neural-network

I'm trying to change my Neural Net from using sigmoid activation for hidden and output layer to tanh function.
I'm confused what i should change. just the output calculation for the neurons or also error calculation for back propagation?
this is the output calculation:

```
public void calcOutput() 
{
    if (!isBias) 
    {
        float sum = 0;
        float bias = 0;
        //System.out.println("Looking through " + connections.size() + " connections");
        for (int i = 0; i < connections.Count; i++) 
        {
            Connection c = (Connection) connections[i];
            Node from = c.getFrom();
            Node to = c.getTo();
            // Is this connection moving forward to us
            // Ignore connections that we send our output to
            if (to == this) 
            {
                // This isn't really necessary
                // But I am treating the bias individually in case I need to at some point
                if (from.isBias) bias = from.getOutput()*c.getWeight();
                else sum += from.getOutput()*c.getWeight();
            }
        }
        // Output is result of sigmoid function
        output = Tanh(bias+sum);
    }
}
```

it works great for how i trained it before, but now i want want to train it to give 1 or -1 as output.
when i change 
    output = Sigmoid(bias+sum);
to
    output = Tanh(bias+sum);
the result are all messed up...

Sigmoid:

```
public static float Sigmoid(float x) 
{
    return 1.0f / (1.0f + (float) Mathf.Exp(-x));
}
```

Tanh:

```
public float Tanh(float x)
{
    //return (float)(Mathf.Exp(x) - Mathf.Exp(-x)) / (Mathf.Exp(x) + Mathf.Exp(-x));
    //return (float)(1.7159f * System.Math.Tanh(2/3 * x));
    return (float)System.Math.Tanh(x);
}
```

as you can see i tried different formula i found for tanh but none the outputs make sense, i get -1 where i ask 0 or 0.76159 where i ask 1 or it keeps flipping between a positive and a negative number when asking -1 and other mismatches...

-EDIT- updated currently working code (changed the above calcOuput to what i use now):

```
public float[] train(float[] inputs, float[] answer) 
{
    float[] result = feedForward(inputs);
    deltaOutput = new float[result.Length];

    for(int ii=0; ii<result.Length; ii++)
    {
        deltaOutput[ii] = 0.66666667f * (1.7159f - (result[ii]*result[ii]))  * (answer[ii]-result[ii]);
    }

    // BACKPROPOGATION

    for(int ii=0; ii<output.Length; ii++)
    {
        ArrayList connections = output[ii].getConnections();
        for (int i = 0; i < connections.Count; i++) 
        {
            Connection c = (Connection) connections[i];
            Node node = c.getFrom();
            float o = node.getOutput();
            float deltaWeight = o*deltaOutput[ii];
            c.adjustWeight(LEARNING_CONSTANT*deltaWeight);
        }
    }

    // ADJUST HIDDEN WEIGHTS
    for (int i = 0; i < hidden.Length; i++) 
    {
        ArrayList connections = hidden[i].getConnections();
        //Debug.Log(connections.Count);
        float sum  = 0;
        // Sum output delta * hidden layer connections (just one output)
        for (int j = 0; j < connections.Count; j++) 
        {
            Connection c = (Connection) connections[j];
            // Is this a connection from hidden layer to next layer (output)?
            if (c.getFrom() == hidden[i]) 
            {
                for(int k=0; k<deltaOutput.Length; k++)
                    sum += c.getWeight()*deltaOutput[k];
            }
        }    
        // Then adjust the weights coming in based:
        // Above sum * derivative of sigmoid output function for hidden neurons
        for (int j = 0; j < connections.Count; j++) 
        {
            Connection c = (Connection) connections[j];
            // Is this a connection from previous layer (input) to hidden layer?
            if (c.getTo() == hidden[i]) 
            {
                float o = hidden[i].getOutput();
                float deltaHidden = o * (1 - o);  // Derivative of sigmoid(x)
                deltaHidden *= sum;   
                Node node = c.getFrom();
                float deltaWeight = node.getOutput()*deltaHidden;
                c.adjustWeight(LEARNING_CONSTANT*deltaWeight);
            }
        } 
    }
    return  result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm confused what i should change. just the output calculation for the neurons or also error calculation for back propagation? this is the output calculation:

You should be using the derivative of the sigmoid function somewhere in your backpropagation code. You will also need to replace that with the derivative of the `tanh` function, which is `1 - (tanh(x))^2`.

Your code looks like C#. I get this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Tanh(0));     // prints 0
Console.WriteLine(Math.Tanh(-1));    // prints -0.761594155955765
Console.WriteLine(Math.Tanh(1));     // prints 0.761594155955765
Console.WriteLine(Math.Tanh(0.234)); // prints 0.229820548214317
Console.WriteLine(Math.Tanh(-4));    // prints -0.999329299739067
```

Which is in line with the `tanh` plot:

[image: Plot of the tanh function]

I think you're reading the results wrong: you get the correct answer for `1`. Are you sure you get `-1` for `tanh(0)`?

If you're sure there's a problem, please post more code.

Comment: thanks IVlad, i edited my question adding the code for the Train method, which i updated using your answer. but still getting strange results... maybe i didn't change it right?

Comment: @Rottjung I don't see any edit to your question... it's the same as when I answered it.

Comment: sorry commented before i edited :-) and yes it's C#.

Comment: ah ok i changed my error calculation to:       deltaOutput[ii] = 0.66666667f * (1.7159f - (result[ii]*result[ii]))  * (answer[ii]-result[ii]);    now it seems to work :-)

Comment: so like you said i needed to change my derivative for OutputDelta and HiddenDelta.
The one you gave worked for the HiddenDelta calculation but not for the OutputDelta. if you add this in with the one i posted above for the Output delta i can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @Rottjung even if it seems to work, I don't think it's right. You shouldn't have any magic numbers in your derivatives. You're using `exp`, but you should raise the tangent to the power of 2, like I posted. Also, if `o` already has `tanh` applied to it, then what you want is not `1 - tanh(o)^2`, but `1 - o*o`. Please try these changes.

Comment: @ IVlad: I got the derivative for the Output error from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632976/neural-network-with-tanh-wrong-saturation-with-normalized-data?rq=1"Answer"). answer.
I see, now I'm getting confused. I can change 
    1 - tanh(o)^2 
back to 
    1 - o*o 
for the hidden layer error calculation without any noticeable effect on the result. I can not change 
    deltaOutput[ii] = (2f/3f) * (1.7159f - (result[ii]*result[ii])) * (answer[ii]-result[ii]); 
to
    1 - tanh(result[ii])^2 
without the output going haywire. ps: sorry can't seem to get the indent to work...?

Comment: @Rottjung try changing the delta output to `(answer[ii] - result[ii]) * (1 - result[ii] * result[ii])`

Comment: @Vlad if i put (answer[ii] - result[ii]) * (1 - result[ii] * result[ii]) back for output error calculation, it's all messed up again.

Comment: @Rottjung messed up how? Can you fix it if you tweak the learning rate?

Comment: [here](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf) from page 10 on, is a good explanation of why the constant 1.7159f is in the derivative.
messed up as in asking 0, 1 getting instant -1,-1 or asking 0,-1 getting 0,0, learning rate 0,5 or 0,1 doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Rottjung I know the paper, but it's an optimization. I thought you were using the basic form of the tanh function. If you're using Lecun's version, then yes, you should also use the proper derivative.

Comment: ok so if i use MathTanh(x) as activation function in my forward feed, i should be able to use the derivative (answer[ii] - result[ii]) * (1 - result[ii] * result[ii]) for the output error calculation and 1 - o * o for the hidden error calculation? because thats how i started and it didn't give the expected results.
I now have still the same Tanh as activation function but with the changes discussed here and it gives the proper results? but if there is something wrong i sure like to find out what.

Comment: updated original post, let me know if you need more, like the code used for training orso.

Comment: @Rottjung if you use `0.66666667f * (1.7159f - (result[ii]*result[ii]))` for the output neurons, then, if you use the same form of the tanh function for the hidden layers, you should also use this form of the derivative for them. If the hidden layers use simple tanh, then your current code is correct.